# Install Ansible on OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, ansible

I am using `OSX.10.12.4`.

I downloaded ansible from github and trying to run it.
Here is what I've got when execute ansible.

```
$> ansible
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: 'module' object has no attribute '_vendor'
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juneyoungoh/Documents/DEV_TEST/ansible/ansible/bin/ansible", line 88, in <module>
    mycli = getattr(__import__("ansible.cli.%s" % sub, fromlist=[myclass]), myclass)
  File "/Users/juneyoungoh/Documents/DEV_TEST/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/yaml/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/yaml/cyaml.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/_yaml.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/_yaml.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    packaging = pkg_resources._vendor.packaging
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_vendor'
```

I got 2 version of python in local(`2.7.10` and `3.6.1`). It could be a cause of this error? What should I do to fix this?

- I do want to install this with binary source, not with `brew install ansible` or `pip install ansible`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you're failing because of some dependency. Ansible provides a `requirements.txt` that you should use with `pip install -r`.

It works for me:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
cd ansible
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py install
```

And the proof:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.0
  config file = 
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/amadeu/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

For installing ansible in mac OSX, the recommended way is using pip.

First you need to install pip using command

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

or

```
sudo python -m ensure pip   //(installing pip via python)
```

Then install ansible with

```
sudo pip install ansible
```

After completion, you can check the version of ansible with

```
ansible —version
```

Now Ansible is installed successfully. Now to communicate with client machines, SSH authentication is required. I assume that SSH is setup.

Now ansible will look for hosts file which contains all IPs of clients. Go to /etc/ansible/ path. If the path doesn’t exist, go to /etc and create directory with name ‘ansible’
    sudo mkdir ansible

cd in to that and create hosts file.

```
cd ansible
sudo vi hosts
```

Edit your hosts file something like this.

```
[clients]
10.20.200.211           //Replace with your client’s ip address
```

Now try to ping all your clients

```
ansible all -m ping
```

Expected output is something like this.

```
10.20.200.211 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Now you can create and play with playbook files :)

Answer (score 1):

In alternative way, I solved with below.

1. Install `python3`, in order to use `pip3`
2. `sudo pip3 install pyyaml`
3. `sudo pip3 install ansible`
4. `sudo pip3 install ansible --upgrade`

when you type `pip`, it will use the original system `python`.(Maybe `2.7.0` in my case)

Answer (score 0):

**Simply 3 steps to install ansible on mac os x 11**

```
 pip3 install ansible

 sudo mkdir -p /etc/ansible

 sudo nano /etc/ansible/hosts
```

add server ip's to the hosts file

[web]

198.20.200.211           //Replace with your client’s ip address

check the status of the connection

```
ansible all -m ping
```